# How to reordering table row in ASP.Net MVC3 using jquery without using any plugin?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
I am using datatable plugin in my ASP.Net MVC3 project. Here I have to implement the row reordering. I used "jQuery.dataTables.rowReordering.js" plugin to implement it. For ui its working fine, but It failed to call server side function.
```

I am using datatable plugin in my ASP.Net MVC3 project. Here I have to implement the row reordering. I used "jQuery.dataTables.rowReordering.js" plugin to implement it. For ui its working fine, but It failed to call server side function.

I am using datatable plugin in my ASP.Net MVC3 project. Here I have to implement the row reordering. I used "jQuery.dataTables.rowReordering.js" plugin to implement it. For ui its working fine, but It failed to call server side function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('#myDataTable').dataTable().rowReordering({sURL: "/AdminArea/UpdateOrder" });
    });

</script>

my controller code is   


public void UpdateOrder( int id, int fromPosition, int toPosition, string direction )
    {

        if( direction == "back" )
        {
            var movedCompanies = objEpisodeDL.GetAllSegmentsByEpisodeId( 2 )
                        .Where( c => ( toPosition <= c.DisplayOrder && c.DisplayOrder <= fromPosition ) )
                        .ToList();

            foreach( var company in movedCompanies )
            {
                company.DisplayOrder++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var movedCompanies = objEpisodeDL.GetAllSegmentsByEpisodeId( 2 )
                        .Where( c => ( fromPosition <= c.DisplayOrder && c.DisplayOrder <= toPosition ) )
                        .ToList();
            foreach( var company in movedCompanies )
            {
                company.DisplayOrder--;
            }
        }

        objEpisodeDL.GetAllSegmentsByEpisodeId( 2 ).First( c => c.Id == id ).DisplayOrder = toPosition;

    }
```

view is-

```
<table id="myDataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            OrderNo
        </th>        
        <th>
            SubArea
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>        

    </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
@{
    if (@ViewData["SubAreaForArea"] != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<GridDragAndDrop.Models.SubAreaForAdmin> subarea = ViewData["SubAreaForArea"] as IEnumerable<GridDragAndDrop.Models.SubAreaForAdmin>;

        foreach (var item in subarea)
        {
            <tr class="order">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.OrderNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubArea)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `public void UpdateOrder` => try using `public ActionResult UpdateOrder` and return ordered data in JSON format.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto   I tried...but not working....

Comment: need a help...please